# Using sensor manager in android programming

Tags: android

I'm new in android programming and now I have a problem.
I want to use sensor manager in an old openGL program in netbeans IDE.
but when i create a class that extends activity and implements sensorListener , it doesn't work.
Could u plz help me?

and another question:
how can i simulate motion sensor in my computer?

Best Regards

Answer (score 2):

***how can i simulate motion sensor in my computer?***

> Check out this tool called [Sensor Simulator](http://code.google.com/p/openintents/wiki/SensorSimulator)

---

Make sure you have declared

```
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy)
```

and

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the following methods :

```
SensorEventListener sel = new SensorEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            //Your code here
        }

        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
           //Your code here
        }
    };
```